# Django project has a 'lib' folder with all of the dependence but when i run project, it gives an import error

Tags: python, django, linux, python-2.7

I have been struggling with this for a while.  I am trying to run an old Django 1.2 project but i keep getting an error saying "ImportError: No module named appengine.ext".  I know that the module is inside the folder called 'lib' but how do i tell python to search there.  I have tried to set $PYTHONPATH to the folder but it still is not working.  I am using python 2.7

Comment: are you positive that you are using the correct virtualenv?

Comment: it is a old project. how can i find the virtual env

Comment: is there a requirements.txt file inside the project?

Comment: sadly there is not. the project is like 10 years old.

Comment: can you try pip install virtualenv? if you dont have pip install that first

Comment: i have that installed already

Comment: cool, can you try "virtualenv -p /home/username/your_python_directory/python-2.7.15/bin/python venv" at your project directory (where your manage.py is)

Comment: i completed that step and there is a venv folder.  This project does not have a manage.py file; the closets thing i could find was a main.py

Comment: Then how are you trying to run the project? The command to run a django project is "python manage.py runserver"

Comment: i run "python main.py runserver."  this is a contract job i got to fix bugs for a site.  Sadly i cannot even run it.  :(

Comment: is there perhaps another file i should be looking for?

Comment: no man, you are almost there. you were talking about a "lib" directory. is it a random folder in the project?

Comment: yhea in the root folder, there is file called 'lib' which has all the dependencies that i would need.  When i push the project to google cloud it works; just not in local host

Comment: can you try copying all the files inside that folder and pasting them into "your_virtual_env/python/site-packages/"

Comment: sadly it did not work

Comment: Weird. Jusy to be certain, can you deactivate virtualenv and start the one you have copied the files again?